# Android checkstyle - debug custom checks

Tags: android-studio, debugging, gradle, checkstyle

I want to write a custom check for [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) 8.1. I successfully install and configurate Gradle Checkstyle and write sketch of my check. But when I try to run my check - i got error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkstyle'.
> Unable to process files: FILE1, FILE2 ...
```

Here is my Check code

```
package com.lsurvila.checkstyle;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.*;

import javax.xml.ws.LogicalMessage;

public class LinesAfterClassJavadocCheck extends AbstractCheck
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 30;
    private int max = DEFAULT_MAX;

    /**
     * Returns the default token a check is interested in. Only used if the
     * configuration for a check does not define the tokens.
     *
     * @return the default tokens
     * @see TokenTypes
     */
    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[]{TokenTypes.CLASS_DEF, TokenTypes.INTERFACE_DEF};
    }

    /**
     * The configurable token set.
     * Used to protect Checks against malicious users who specify an
     * unacceptable token set in the configuration file.
     * The default implementation returns the check's default tokens.
     *
     * @return the token set this check is designed for.
     * @see TokenTypes
     */
    @Override
    public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
        return new int[0];
    }

    /**
     * The tokens that this check must be registered for.
     *
     * @return the token set this must be registered for.
     * @see TokenTypes
     */
    @Override
    public int[] getRequiredTokens() {
        return new int[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast)
    {
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException("SUKA BLEAT");
        DetailAST objBlock1 = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_CLASS);
        if (objBlock1 == null) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(), "PIDOR");
            //System.out.print("PIDOR");
        }

        String a = getLine(objBlock1.getLineNo()-1);
        log(1,a);
        //System.out.print(a);
        if (a.isEmpty()) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(), "PIDOR1");
        }

        /*DetailAST objBlock2 = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.MODIFIERS).findFirstToken(TokenTypes.BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN);
        if (objBlock2 == null) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(), "PIDOR1");
            //System.out.print("PIDOR");
        }*/

        /*DetailAST objBlock2 = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_CLASS);

        DetailAST objBlock3 = objBlock1.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.MODIFIERS).findFirstToken(TokenTypes.BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN).findFirstToken(TokenTypes.BLOCK_COMMENT_END);




        if (objBlock3.getLine()+2 != objBlock2.getLine()) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(), "PIDOR");
        }*/
    }
}
```

I found out that log() method produce this exception. I did not find another way to see what is happening inside my code - even System.out.print() don't show anything. How can I run debugger attached to my custom check? The situation is complicated by the fact that my check is started BEFORE the application is compiled.

Here is screenshoot how checks placed in my app project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NycVe.png)

*Please sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Command line interface](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html#Command_line_usage) to see the raw output and errors of Checkstyle. I don't specifically know how gradle handles these situations, but `System.out` should work form the CLI. If you still get no output, it could be that `visitToken` isn't even being called.

I also recommend using the `-t` option to look at the AST tree of your file to verify you are grabbing the right tokens for your check.

> ```
>     return new int[0];
> ```

This is wrong, you must return a token for `Acceptable` otherwise you are saying your check accepts nothing. Change it to return `getDefaultTokens`.

I recommend getting help from the group at [their google group form](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/checkstyle-devel).